# the selector in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the object of this code ,

```
<input class="radio" 
       id="conversation_sub_kind_id_208"
       name="conversation[sub_kind_id]"
       onclick="set_department_name('department_name208')"
       type="radio"
       value="208" />
```

I want to use jQuery Framework to get the object, like the `document.getElementbyTagName("conv...");` what should i do in here?
Thank you, and best regards!

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#conversation_sub_kind_id_208');
```

[more here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as `$('#conversation_sub_kind_id_208')`. That would give you the jQuery object. If you want the underlying DOM element, do it like this: `$('#conversation_sub_kind_id_208').get(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could not use Jquery and simply do:
`document.getElementById("conversation_sub_kind_id_208");`